# Sending data from js client to py server via socket don't work

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, sockets, client-server

i'm trying to send some data via socket from js to py server.

JS Client:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:1729');
    socket.send("1234");   
</script>
```

Py Server:

```
import socket
server_socket4=socket.socket()
server_socket4.bind(('localhost', 1729))
server_socket4.listen(1)
(client_socket,client_adress)=server_socket4.accept()
print client_socket.recv(1024)
server_socket4.close()
```

It's printing this:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M1KiY71 HTTP/1.1
Referer: http://localhost:8000/index.html
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,he;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:1729
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

How can I make it print "1234"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [Socket io](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-socketio) module for python as well... Classic socket won't work.